Material is missing
can someone please help me with this material missing situation. No material from the package covering the white part of the head.  can someone please tell whats the problem?



No material from what package? We need more details to have any chance of answering that! At least add a screenshot of your full Blender screen (Window > Save Screenshot in Blender) so that we can see if there's supposed to be a second material on your object.

Hi, first thing I would look into is to check material slots - remove any other slots with  - , or make sure all faces of the model have assigned the same "skin" material. Other, but less likely, would be to check the UV map of your model, to see any distortion or mesh being split that would cause them to be on some kind of white area of a texture. Hope this helps!

Are you sure you connected the basecolor to the correct image?

If none of these solution yield results it would probably be most helpful to share your Blender project file. Instructions for sharing.

@DanielMöller hey! thank you for your help! yes, the basecolor conencted to texturediffuse image

Hey John! @JohnEason thank you, it is the package of the downloaded model. I do have actually the texture for the backhead. but I am confused where exactly connect it.

@DanielMöller thanks, I solved the issuel :)

@JanHrodek thank you very much, I solved it, did not see other materials.

@Jakemoyo thank you very much, friend! but i solved)

You should be able to answer your own question, that way if someone else has a similar problem they can find this question in the future and get the answer. It doesn't matter if you solve it yourself or if someone else answers for you, just that it is answered, ultimately.
